# can you help me with this error on my project?

Tags: java, opencv, netbeans, javacv

when click button run...
in output....

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
OpenCV Error: Insufficient memory (Failed to allocate 6220800 bytes) in unknown function, file ..\..\..\src\opencv\modules\core\src\alloc.cpp, line 52
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.RuntimeException: ..\..\..\src\opencv\modules\core\src\alloc.cpp:52: error: (-4) Failed to allocate 6220800 bytes    
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvCloneImage(Native Method)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.clone(opencv_core.java:521)
    at vidtracking.MainView.backgroundSubtraction(MainView.java:666)
    at vidtracking.MainView.access$1000(MainView.java:32)
    at vidtracking.MainView$8.run(MainView.java:461)
```

Comment: Sharing of code will be more helpful in answering this.

Comment: looks like you need to allocate more memory in your JVM for that project.

Comment: Are you running it from eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError OpenCV Error: Insufficient memory
```

It seems you are loading large file into memory. Try to [increase memory using -Xms and -Xmx settings](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/06/6-common-errors-in-setting-java-heap.html).

If you have more memory than file size, then possible cause could be some memory leaks.

Comment: yes this file input too large, so it makes me to reinstall my netbeans or opencv?can you give me the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate atleast 6220800 bytes (i.e. ~6mb).
Run your java app with these jvm settings (to allocate more heap size):

```
java myapp.jar -Xms10m -Xmx10m
```

For eclipse:

```
Windows Preferences -> java -> Installed JREs:
Select JRE/JDK you are using
Click Edit
Set VM arguments: -Xms10m -Xmx10m
Start your app again.
```

Answer (score 0):

Its symptom of JVM crash or no memory for allocation of resource in JVM. try to tune your program or increase JVM memory